# Angular change the value of a variable in URL

Tags: angularjs, variables, url, routes, location

I am currently having a problem where I can not change the value of the parameters in the URL. This is my URL : http://localhost/details

I would like to add or swap an "inverse" parameter in the URL when I filter my table, like the following : http://localhost/details?inverse=false or http://localhost/details?inverse=true every time i submit the form with inverse checkbox selected or not.

Here is how to get the params from the URL:

```
var paramsURL = $location.search();
// If params in URL
if( Object.keys(paramsURL).length > 0) {
    if ( paramsURL.hasOwnProperty('reverse')){
         $scope.reverse = paramsURL.reverse;
    }
}
```

If the URl has an inverse param to true of false, then I store it and apply it in the request. This works perfectly so far.

The problem is to change dynamically the URL when the user submits the form .

I tried the following things but no one them work:

```
$location.search('reverse', $scope.reverse).replace();
```

or

```
$location.search({reverse:$scope.reverse});
```

$scope.reverse exists because it has a default value but i can not change the URL to match its value.

Does anyone already got this problem before ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If got your requirement correctly, you need to set new value in query params dynamically. You can try following

```
$location.path('/currentPath').search({key: value});
```

**key:** will be `reverse`

**value:** will be set to `true` or `false` dynamically

above setter method allows chaining for multiple values